# Porfavor alguien podria decrime si la sintaxis de la consulta de esas tablas esta bien?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ConsultarLibro  
@id_Libro char(3)  
as  
Select  
IdLibro,   
Titulo,  
NomApe_Autor,  
Nombre_Categoria,   
Nombre_Editorial,  
Nombre_Idioma,  
Año_Lanz  
FROM  LIBRO L  
INNER JOIN AUTOR A ON L.IdAutor = A.IdAutor  
INNER JOIN CATEGORIA C ON L.IdCategoria = C.IdCategoria  
INNER JOIN EDITORIAL E ON L.IdEditorial = E.IdEditorial  
INNER JOIN IDIOMA I ON L.IdIdioma = I.IdIdioma  
where IdLibro=@id_Libro  
GO
```

es necesario poner las abreviaturas antes de los nombres de los campos?

Comment: `¿es necesario poner las abreviaturas antes de los nombres de los campos?` eventualmente lo es si hay columnas con el mismo nombre en más de una tabla de la consulta, pero de todas formas te diría que es una buena práctica usar siempre los alias.

Comment: Yo creo que la etiqueta "c#" e incluso la de "base-de-datos" (ya que las de sql-server u stored-procedure las hacen implicitas) están de mas.

Comment: Gracias recien estoy empezando en este ambiente :D lo hare

Answer (score 1):

Si, deberías poner el  nombre del alias antes de los los atributos del select (L.IdLibro, L.Titulo, etc).

Dependiendo del gestor que estés usando te puede ayudar el autocompletado o no. En el caso de Oracle sí ayuda.

Comment: Si lo que pasa es que estoy conectando esa base de datos a una aplicacion en visual studio y nose si tengo que poner con toda y alias